# Trying Login with Plaid APi

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i Login with plaid Api in live credential, it shows this type of error.

```
  {
    code = 1106;
    message = "bad public_token";
    resolve = "This public_token is corrupt or does not exist in our database. See https://plaid.com/docs/link for docs.";
}
```

so Any idea about that? Help me.

Comment: Well, it will be nice if you add up some code so that SO users can understand how you are getting the error.

Comment: just tell me how we implement code based authantication in plaid.

Comment: Then show us the code how you have implemented it! Then we will have a conversation  about this.